# Python and pandas: subtracting and formatting dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to subtract two data frames in python 2.x and format the result to be in hh:mm:ss.
My problem is that I am assuming the delta column is a string and it's a number.
I need help because I am struggling to make it work. I've searched and tried some solutions found on other posts but I am unable to solve it.

```
actual= ...select now()
```

This is the df

```
        begin                         actual
0  2018-01-31 16:45:04.263      2018-01-31 16:48:06
1  2018-01-31 16:10:26.000      2018-01-31 16:50:06
```

Now:

```
df['actual'] = pd.to_datetime(df['actual'])
df['delta'] = df['actual'] - df['begin'] 
df['delta'] = df['delta'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[-8:])
```

The result it's this:
 39:49 and 2.737000 . For the second one I want the same format as for the first.
I've tried changing the function like this:

```
df['delta'] = df['delta'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(seconds=int(x.total_seconds())))
```

But it returns :

```
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Comment: please note that to get better answers you should try to include all relevant tags when posting your question. In this case pandas is much more relevant than simply python

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty new to python and still learning

Comment: in fact I am giving you advice on how to post better question on stackoverflow. Please try to keep this in mind when posting questions in future.

Comment: I'll do. Thank you

Comment: @RamonaDaniela - What is expected output? Do you need `df['delta'] = (df['actual'] - df['begin']).dt.total_seconds()` ?

Comment: No. The delta it's the actual - begin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
print (df.dtypes)
begin     datetime64[ns]
actual    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object


df['delta'] = (df['actual'] - df['begin']).dt.total_seconds()
print (df)
                    begin              actual     delta
0 2018-01-31 16:45:04.263 2018-01-31 16:48:06   181.737
1 2018-01-31 16:10:26.000 2018-01-31 16:50:06  2380.000
```

If want format it is possible, but a bit crazy (not general solution, because days are removed):

```
df['delta'] = (df['actual'] - df['begin']).astype(str).str[7:15]
print (df)
                    begin              actual     delta
0 2018-01-31 16:45:04.263 2018-01-31 16:48:06  00:03:01
1 2018-01-31 16:10:26.000 2018-01-31 16:50:06  00:39:40
```

---

```
df['delta'] = (df['actual'] - df['begin']).astype(str)
print (df)
                    begin              actual                      delta
0 2018-01-31 16:45:04.263 2018-01-31 16:48:06  0 days 00:03:01.737000000
1 2018-01-31 16:10:26.000 2018-01-31 16:50:06  0 days 00:39:40.000000000
```

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev - Ineteresing, it is implemented in `0.17.0` version of pandas. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev - Waht is `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: @jezrael sorry my bad, your solution works as expected I was using a 'mixed' solution using apply(stupid me). I can confirm that your solution works for both version of pandas. jp's solution works on 0.22 but not on 0.17.1